# How to pass Laravel CSRF token to Service Worker so i can make a POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, service-worker

So I've got a Laravel application that utilises a service worker for caching and web push notifications. I'm trying to pass an action to the web push notifications so when it pops up on the users device, it gives them 2 options - Accept or Reject. Clicking on either of these options will fire off a POST request to my Laravel application updating the users status.
Here is my service-worker.js file:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

    var notification = event.notification;
    var action = event.action;

    notification.close();

    switch (action) {
        case 'close':
            console.log('[Service Worker] close Action Clicked');
            break;
        case 'view':
            console.log('[Service Worker] view Action Clicked')
            event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(notification.data.url));
            break;
        case 'accept-player':
            console.log('[Service Worker] accept-player Action Clicked')

           fetch(notification.data.url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
                },
                body: { accepted:1 },
            }).catch(error => {
               console.error(error)
           });

            break;
        case 'reject-player':
            console.log('[Service Worker] reject-player Action Clicked')
            fetch(notification.data.url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
                },
                body: { accepted:0 },
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

Within my switch, i'm specifically referring to `accept-player` and `reject-player` cases for the fetch.

Typically I get the CSRF token from my HTML HEAD but in this case `document` doesn't exist so it can't get it. I get the following error in console:

```
sw.js:86 Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How can I pull in the CSRF token to my service-worker.js so I can make a POST request?

I did some reading and I'm not sure whether I should be disabling CSRF verification for this one particular route either.

Hoping someone can help with this.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a new endpoint to your laravel app which returns the csrf token?

Comment: Surely this would eliminate the purpose of the csrf token? If anyone can request it and attach it to a HTTP request, that makes my app vulnerable to CSRF attacks. I might as well disable csrf verification on this route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is proving quite difficult and I decided to change my approach. Although disabling CSRF verification on this particular route is helpful, my route requires Auth and the service worker has no Auth setup to handle the request.

Instead of doing a POST request from my service-worker to my app, I am doing a redirect to another GET route with some additional parameters e.g. "showPlayersPending=1". Then in my view, I am merely wrapping an if around the request if it has "showPlayersPending" then to show the modal on load so the authenticated user can action the POST request.